# Web IDE for IronPython with intellisense

Tags: ironpython, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for a web control that can support writing IronPython scripts. Ideally the control will support syntax highlighting and intellisense\code completion.

Anyone know of any control (commercial or not) that can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [**Try Python**](http://code.google.com/p/trypython/) open source project:

> An interactive [Python](http://www.python.org/) interpreter that runs in the browser,
>   using [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/GetStarted/) and [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython).

This is also what the folks at [ironpython.net](http://ironpython.net) are running for their interactive [tutorials](http://ironpython.net/try/).